# How to integrate Kettle with H2

Tags: pentaho, hsqldb, h2, kettle

I am trying to integrate Kettle (v 5.4.0) with an in memory relational database like h2 or hsqldb. I tried some versions of h2 and hsqldb but I am not able to connect to these dbs from spoon in an outputTable component, I am getting connection exceptions (which I have searched the web - but no answer from  pentaho ) or kettle is crashing.

Has anyone succeeded in doing this?

the versions of the kettle, h2 or hsqldb don't really matter.

Really need some help here...

Comment: show the configuration to connect to h2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally it worked but with Kettle 5.1.0 and h2-1.2.131 version
The configuration which worked was:

Connection Type: Generic Database

Access: Native (JDBC)

Custom Connection URL: jdbc:h2:~/test

Custom Driver Class Name: org.h2.Driver

User Name: sa

Password: sa

If you have a configuration with the latest Kettle and H2 please share it to me, but as I have investigated latest Kettle version, it seems that it does not integrate successfully at least with h2 or hsqldb